# Can a nested class be derived from an interface

Tags: java, interface

I have a class structure as follows:

```
  public class A implements IA {
      // class variables and method

      private class C implements Serializable{
      }
  }
```

Can I create an interface like IC and C implements IC ? I am doing this because A contains a method which returns C and I want to include this in IA.

Comment: There is no reason why it should not work... Have you tried?

Comment: No I am asking...is this a right way ...good for s/w development...?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of what you should do, the first question should be;

> Is this the simplest and clearest way to write this code?

You can have nested interfaces, classes, enums and even nested @interface annotations.

BTW: You can have classes nested in interfaces (which looks like code inside an interface ;)